# Avoid writing "replace" for recursive dependency for local modules

Tags: go, go-modules

I'm trying to switch from *GOPATH* to *Go Module*. I have many local modules that used by many executable, I can't put them online for security reason.

When module "d" depends on three packages: "a", "b", "c", I need to "replace" in go.mod:

```
replace m.y/a => /my/a
replace m.y/b => /my/b
replace m.y/c => /my/c
```

When an executable imports package "d", it doesn't import a/b/c directly, but it still requires the "replace a,b,c" in the go.mod:

```
replace m.y/a => /my/a
replace m.y/b => /my/b
replace m.y/c => /my/c

replace m.y/d => /my/d
```

Is it by design or I'm using it wrong? Since a/b/c is already in d's go.mod, why do I have to write them again for every executable that using d?

Does go module support import from another go.mod?  Or is it possible to not write "replace a/b/c" again and again ?

Comment: What happens when you don't put the replaces in the module importing "d"?

Comment: It is [by design that only the main package can process `replace` directives](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace). If your module dependencies themselves require local replacemenets in order to function, they are broken.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco It fails to run if remove the "replace a/b/c" in executable's go.mod, something like "go: d requires a...", it will try to fetch them by http Get request, and fail.

Comment: I'd also recommend looking closely at whether these should really be four separate modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. Per https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace:

> replace directives only apply in the main module's `go.mod` file and are ignored in other modules. See [Minimal version selection](https://golang.org/ref/mod#minimal-version-selection) for details.

If you have a set of packages that are tightly coupled and cannot be published even on a local or private server, then they should probably be part of a single module (`module m.y`) instead of split into separate ones (`module m.y/a`, `module m.y/b`, etc.).

On the other hand, if you *can* publish them on a private server, then you can use a `.netrc` file to provide credentials to the `go` command, and the `GOPRIVATE` environment variable to instruct it not to look for checksums in the public checksum database. See https://golang.org/ref/mod#private-modules for more detail.

Answer (score 3):

`replace` shouldn't be used to fix your source code. It's used to fix your build configuration, usually temporarily or for the development environment only.

If the import strings for your packages have permanently changed, you need to update the source code that imports them. This is one reason why you want to avoid renaming packages or modules.